# phonegap empty created directory after photo is uploaded

Tags: cordova, directory, android-camera

I have a phonegap app that takes a picture then do some editing and store it in a temp folder, it is then uploaded to the server.

code for creating directory

```
var entry=fileSystem.root;      
entry.getDirectory("DCIM/Temp", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
```

Is there a way to empty the folder after the upload is done?

Or is there another way of doing this like storing it in the application cache?

Open to suggestions as well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use the temp directory as done above and clear it using: camera.cleanup API method. Not sure about this if it works fine or not.
2. Create you own directory in sd card of phone, store image, edit it, upload it and then delete the contents of the directory, a much longer way, if above doesn't work.

Comment: Want to delete pictures what you have given is the process, I am probably using 2. Can you give some reference link on how to do this or what code can I use to actually delete the picture, thanks

Comment: btw checked the camera cleanup it is only for ios seen [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.cleanup.md.html)